# Python - Printing a CSV file into the console as a table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, printing

I have been trying to print a csv file into the console in such way that it is structured like a table.

--> Desiered output:

```
Key   Field_1   Field_2   Field_3   Field_4
A0    B0        C0        D0        E0
A1    B1        C1        D1        E1
A2    B2        C2        D2        E2
```

But instead with the next methods I have tried I have been unable to get it.

--> CSV File

```
Key,Field_1,Field_2,Field_3,Field_4
A0,B0,C0,D0,E0
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2
```

--> Method 1:

```
import csv

file = "file.csv"
opened = open(file, "r")
readed = csv.reader(opened, delimiter=",")
for row in readed:
    print(row)
```

--> Output of Method 1:

```
["Key", "Field_1", "Field_2", "Field_3", "Field_4"]
["A0", "B0", "C0", "D0", "E0"]
["A1", "B1", "C1", "D1", "E1"]
["A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2"]
```

Method 1 prints me all the values correctly but I didnt find any way so it gets printed like my desire output.

--> Method 2:

```
import pandas as pd

file = "file.csv"
opened = open(file, "r")
readed = pd.read_csv(file)
print(readed)
```

--> Output of Method 2:

```
Key   Field_1   ...   Field_4
A0    B0        ...        E0
A1    B1        ...        E1
A2    B2        ...        E2
```

Because of the length of the values Im using and the number of fields I have, part of the columns are getting cutten out, only leaving me with part of the information. ( Maybe it works for the table I have showed here, but in my case Fields A-E may have up to 20 characteres each )

I have not encountered any other method which would work to give me the first value, method 1 and 2 being the ones I mostly tried to use to get my desired output.

Thanks.

Comment: See also [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data).

Comment: Method 1: `print('\t'.join(row))` work?

Comment: @roganjosh Almost, that gets rid of the [] but the spacing is not correct, so the headers and values are not in phase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your desired formatting, using Pandas would be your best bet. To get around the ellipses for columns, you can change the `display.max_columns` option for Pandas.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

file = "file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)
pd.options.display.max_columns = len(df.columns)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you consider using [`tabulate`](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) in conjunction with `pandas`. Drawing on this:

> I have been trying to print a csv file into the console in such way that it is structured like a table.

If your main objective is to control the nature of output, by using `tabulate` you will be able to specify a number of presentational details, such as presence of borders, text alignment display of headers and index.

## Example

Producing tabular output with a `heavy_grid` formatting applied to a sample csv.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
print(tabulate(pd.read_csv("grad-adm.csv", nrows=5), 
               headers="keys", tablefmt="heavy_grid"))
```

#### Output

```
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━┓
┃    ┃   columnA ┃   columnB ┃   OtherColumn ┃   rank ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━┫
┃  0 ┃         0 ┃        10 ┃          3.61 ┃      3 ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━┫
┃  1 ┃         1 ┃        20 ┃          3.67 ┃      3 ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━┫
┃  2 ┃         1 ┃        30 ┃          4    ┃      1 ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━┫
┃  3 ┃         1 ┃        40 ┃          3.19 ┃      4 ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━┫
┃  4 ┃         0 ┃        50 ┃          2.93 ┃      4 ┃
┗━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━┛
```

Answer (score -1):

In pandas you can configure the maximum string length using the max_colwidth option:

```
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 10000) have
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work for me, I imagine that it is another way of expresing pd.options.display.max_columns which Henry said, thanks anyway.